# New variable for each group - pandas

Tags: python, r, pandas

I love R. But now I need pandas.
In R I can do:

```
data %>% group_by(sym) %>% mutate(s = mean(price))
```

Its not aggregation ! Its a new variable different for each group.
I try everything in pandas - "group by" want to aggregate or split my data ! I only want to calculate new variable.

Comment: Unfortunately not all pandas specialists have the same level of expertise also with R. So it would be much easier to help you if you could [post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38264474/edit) a sample input data set / data frame (with approx. 5 rows) and a desired output / result data set...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try

```
import pandas as pd
data['s'] = data['price'].groupby(data['sym']).transform('mean')
print(data)
#   price sym           s
#0    125   A  129.000000
#1    133   A  129.000000
#2     50   B   77.333333
#3     62   B   77.333333
#4    120   B   77.333333
```

Or as @MaxU mentioned

```
data['s'] = data.groupby('sym')['price'].transform('mean')
```

#### data

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'sym': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'price': [125, 133, 50, 62, 120]})
```

Comment: i would simplify it a bit: `data.groupby('sym')['price'].transform('mean')`